# How to reset the MSCHart values

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I have a combo-box which contains different names of files and every time i select a value the respective file should be read and respective graphs should be generated. Now as i select the first file the charts are drawn correctly but if i select another value from the combo-box then the charts instead of re-plotting the charts values are added to the existing values..

I tried using serializer but that doesn't seem to work...neither i am able to find a solution anywhere.

Just need to know what i need to add as to reset the existing chart to default value and redraw on every combo-box selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to clear the values from each of your Series.

```
chart.Series["MySeries"].Points.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

`foreach (var series in chart2.Series)
                    {
                        series.Points.Clear();
                    }`